# Docker build context from Github repo with subdirectory

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I’m trying to build a docker context directly from github, where the dockerfiles are placed in a subdirectory. I get the error `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: failed to load cache key: subdir not supported yet`. I’m using Docker Desktop 4.3.1 (72247) on Mac and it seems to be an issue related to BuildKit and buildx. My current version of buildx is `github.com/docker/buildx v0.7.1` and i found in this post (https://www.docker.com/blog/engineering-update-buildkit-0-9-and-docker-buildx-0-6-releases/) that subdirectories from git context are supported from version 0.6! Does anyone have similar problems?

I have tried to turn off BuildKit with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 and COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 but this causes problems on other containers in my compose stack and some temporary containers are not removed after build ending up with a long list of created containers.

This is tested with `docker build https://$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/<my-repo>#develop:mysql`, `docker-compose` version: `1.29.2, build 5becea4c` and `docker compose` version `v2.2.1`. It works for the dockerfile placed in root dir, so the access level works and repo spelling is correct.

Comment: Having the same issue.  Did you get a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by disabling buildkit in Docker Desktop.

- load docker desktop
- go to Preferences
- go to Docker Engine
- edit the settings json. Mine was

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": false
  }
}
```

- Apply and Restart