Docker container build failing on GitHub
I had a repository for a long time with actions set up to automate the build of a Docker container on merge of pull requests.
The issue I am facing is that the code now gets merged, but the build of the container fails with the following error:
#0 building with "builder-d99a4367-77ea-4ed0-93ed-c4feadc1693d" instance using docker-container driver

#1 [internal] load git source https://github.com/***/repo.git#refs/pull/9/merge
#1 0.121 Initialized empty Git repository in /var/lib/buildkit/runc-overlayfs/snapshots/snapshots/1/fs/
#1 ERROR: repository does not contain ref refs/pull/9/merge, output: ""
------
 > [internal] load git source https://github.com/***/repo.git#refs/pull/9/merge:
0.121 Initialized empty Git repository in /var/lib/buildkit/runc-overlayfs/snapshots/snapshots/1/fs/
------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: failed to load cache key: repository does not contain ref refs/pull/9/merge, output: ""
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: failed to load cache key: repository does not contain ref refs/pull/9/merge, output: ""

I cannot figure out what is causing it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me insane.
EDIT
Here's my action workflow:
# This workflow will install Python dependencies, run tests and lint with a single version of Python
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-python

name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python 3.11
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: "3.11"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    #- name: Test with pytest
    #  run: |
    #    pytest

docker:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    -
      name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
      run: echo "::debug::QEMU set up completed"
    -
      name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
      run: echo "::debug::Docker Buildx set up completed"
    -
      name: Login to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v3
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: echo "::debug::Logged in to Docker Hub"
    -
      name: Log environment variables
      run: |
        echo "::debug::GITHUB_REF: $GITHUB_REF"
        echo "::debug::GITHUB_SHA: $GITHUB_SHA"
        echo "::debug::GITHUB_REPOSITORY: $GITHUB_REPOSITORY"
    -
      name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
      with:
        push: true
        tags: xxxxxxx/yyyyyy:latest
      run: echo "::debug::Started building and pushing Docker image"


please provide more context (your github action workflow, your Dockerfile)

#1 Are you using subfolders?  #2 The error is "failed to read dockerfile: failed to load cache key". Research with that sentence like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448058/docker-build-context-from-github-repo-with-subdirectory

I checked the post linked by @JRichardsz but I did not understand how that is somehow related to my issue. The error doesn't look nearly the same. Btw what you mean when you as if I am using subfolders? Which subfolders?

@ShaykiAbramczyk I edited my post to add the workflow file. For reference, the Dockerfile has been working fine for almost 2 years, and there was no change done to it, so I doubt the issue is in it. I was wondering about the "dockefile" spelt in lowercase in the error, if that is somehow indicating that it is looking for a lower case one as mine has capital D.

It is you Dockerfile at the root of your workspace?

@JRichardsz yes, it hasn't moved in 2 years. As I said this has been working totally fine for a very long time, it started failing last week out of the blue.
